# bin of .app not visible using ls or even ls -a

Tags: macos, unix

I noticed something rather interesting yesterday. ls and ls -a don't show the underworking of a .app "directory?", yet you can cd into the bin file of the app if you know the path. Why is this?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  What is an "underworking"?  Are you talking about subdirectories?  What is a `.app` directory?  What did you mean with `"directory?"` in your question?  Is the `?` supposed to be a wildcard?  What is the `bin file` and since when can you `cd` into a file?  I can do that only with directories.  I fear, the way you worded your question it is not fit for SO.

Comment: Apologies very much for the lack of clarity. You can cd to the directory Applications, but you can't see the application files. Yet you can step into applications via cd appname/bin/mexopts.sh for example in matlab.

Comment: What system are you on?  "Unix" isn't very concrete ;-)  What file system are you looking at?  (Using `df DIR` you often can see where directory `DIR` (e. g. `/home/alfe/some/path`) is mounted (e. g. on `/home/alfe`), then `mount | grep /home/alfe` can tell you what kind of file system this is (e. g. `type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon` for encrypted home directories or something simpler like `ext4`).

Comment: yosemite 10.10 cd /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin

Comment: yet if you were to type cd at the Applications directory level you wouldn't see anything except SecureDownloadManager.app and SecureDownloadManager.log

Comment: Sounds like you are on a MacOS X system.  If you had tagged your question accordingly, Mac users would have have a chance to find it ;-) EDIT: I tagged it for you.  Maybe this attracts more attention from the right guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not of the Mac world, but in general, when asked for the contents of a given directory, a file system delivers a list of names; and when asked for a particular entry in that directory it is free to return values even when the entry wasn't listed before.  The two functions are independent in general, but of course most file systems keep these congruent most of the time.  It seems, OSX breaks this congruency deliberately.

Example:

- The file system is asked for the contents of directory `/foo/bar` and it returns the list of the entries `xyz`, `abc`, and `blah`.  This means that the entries `/foo/bar/xyz`, `/foo/bar/abc`, and `/foo/bar/blah` exist.
- When asked for the `stat()` of the path `/foo/bar/ghi`, one could assume that the file system now has to answer with `No Such File` or a similar error.  But in fact, it does not have to.  It can return stats which mean that the path is a directory or similar.

While this is unusual in general, the operating system itself and most tools can handle this situation quite well.  Tools like `ls` or `find` rely on the list of directory entries, so they will process only the entries returned by the file system.  But if given an explicit path (which wasn't part of a list of directory entries), they will process that one.

You can make a test:  If `ls -la /Applications/` doesn't list `MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app`, you will probably still be able to get information by typing `ls -la /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app` directly.

Some more remarks:  Whether you enter that directory (`cd`) is of no concern.  `cd` can be done on any directory which exists and for which (and for whose parents) you have execute permissions, that's all.  The `-a` flag of `ls` lists also files starting with a `.`, but they are not considered "hidden", only "system", i. e. not relevant for normal user interactions.  Most of the dot-files are configuration files etc.